# Conditional AddHandler Directive

Tags: apache, htaccess, handler

**Is it possible to conditionally call AddHandler in the .htaccess under Apache (2.x)?**

My present situation requires that a certain AddHandler is needed by one production server but that one breaks the development server. This requires to have 2 versions of .htaccess which is pain. So, instead I would like to wrap one AddHandler within a conditional. Something of this sort:

```
IF IP=='1.2.3.4' THEN
AddHandler type/foo .ext
ENDIF
```

*The problem is new but out of my control for now. I know this is far from ideal and the servers used to match 100% as they should but temporarily they cannot.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use mod_rewrite and [the H= flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_h).  In .htaccess, use a `-` as the substitution if you set H= in a flag.  You can then do your IP checks in a RewriteCond.

Here's some (untested!) code to accomplish this:

```
# Standard preamble for using mod_rewrite in a root .htaccess file:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks

# Handle .ext files as type/foo if the server address is 1.2.3.4:
RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} =1.2.3.4
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} \.ext$
RewriteRule ^ - [H=type/foo]
```

Comment: +1, excellent suggestion. I edited your answer to add a code example; I didn't test it, though, so any errors in it should be blamed on me.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Apache has very limited support for conditional configurations. Aside from specific modules that have conditional evaluations internally, such as `mod_rewrite`, you're limited to [`<IfDefine>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#ifdefine), [`<IfModule>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#ifmodule), and I believe there's also a way to enable directives based on the existence of a file or directory.

`IfDefine` allows you to enable configurations based on variables defined at startup via `-D`, e.g.

```
httpd -Dstaging
```

Or you can use [`Define`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/core.html#define):

```
Define staging staging
```

Unfortunately, `IfDefine` only evaluates whether the variable is defined, not its value. Though you can't really conditionally define it within your configurations anyway, so it's not much of a loss.

So if you have different modules enabled on your production and staging servers, or if you start your staging server with a custom config variable, then that would be your solution.

Otherwise, I suppose we'll have to wait for the day when someone creates a mod_if that lets us do:

```
DefineIf Server_Addr "127\.0\.0\.1" env=staging:production

<If env=staging>
   AddHandler foo-handler .foo
</If>
```